# php query search a string in a row

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

how to search a string in a row in php? I wrote this code:

```
$filterQuery .=' LIKE %' . $db->Quote(JString::strtolower($filter) . '%');
```

it works in mysql to search string with: LIKE '%stringtosearch%'

why it doesn't work in php?

Comment: You're putting the % outside the ticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your bracketed code adds in quotes around your string, do this instead...

```
$filterQuery .=" LIKE '%" . strtolower($filter) . "%'");
```

Remember you will need to sanitise/escape your data before querying the database

Comment: If you echo out $db->Quote(JString::strtolower($filter), what does it show?

Comment: the output is: 'stringtosearch'

Comment: So does $db->Quote(JString::strtolower($filter) add in quotes around strings?

Comment: but if I try: $filterQuery .=' LIKE ' . $db->Quote(JString::strtolower($filter) . '%'); it works but it finds only word that have mystring in first position.

Comment: Yea thats cos you dont have the % before your string so it will just pick up the matched string at the first position

Comment: So $filter holds the string you want? Could you not just use 
$filterQuery .=" LIKE '%" . strtolower($filter) . "%'");

Comment: This answer is technically not correct. The first code example is wrong (it will lead to a database error), and the second is unsafe because it doesn't explicitly show that `$filter` should be escaped. Either the answer needs to be fixed or another one accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

As already noted, you forget the quotes around the `%...%` part. BUT, MySQL is not case sensitive by default so you can probably remove the `JString` call unless you've specifically configured your MySQL server to be case-sensitive. The alternative usage could then be simplified to:

```
$filterQuery .=' LIKE ' . $db->quote('%' . $filter . '%');
```

Note, however, that if you are using user input, SQL wildcards could result in a DOS attack (the user could include addition % and _ characters in the filter string). To prevent this, you'd use a format like:

```
$filterQuery .=' LIKE ' . $db->quote('%' . $db->escape($filter, true) . '%');
```

and that will escape the filter itself (and allow you to search for real underscores or % characters). This is how the core code handles this case as shown here:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/administrator/components/com_content/models/articles.php#L285

Comment: Great point on the wildcards issue, but iirc doesn't $db->quote() do  escaping at least optionally?

Comment: It may depend on the driver, but at least in MySQL's case, `quote` will escape NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z. It doesn't escape `%` nor `_`. To do that is a funny but necessary two-step process because we want to properly quote (escaping the usual suspects) the entire string, but we don't want the `%`'s that we manually put in to be escaped, but we DO want to exhaustively escape the user input. Guest user input should always be treated this way. For authenticated users, it's up to the developer to work out what they feel comfortable allowing.

Comment: +1 Right, the true on escape($filter, true) adds %_, the escaping in quote() uses the escape() default of false so it all works.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, especially since the actual accepted answer doesn't do anything about escaping the data.

Answer (score 1):

Note: @Andrew Eddie gives a better answer above

```
$filterQuery .=' LIKE ' . $db->quote('%'. JString::strtolower($filter) . '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

if it works like `LIKE '%stringtosearch%'` then add `'`'s before and after `%`'s like so

```
$filterQuery .= " LIKE '%" . $db->Quote(JString::strtolower($filter) . "%' ");
                       ^                                                 ^
```

Comment: $filterQuery .=" LIKE '%" . $db->Quote(JString::strtolower($filter) . "%' ");  nothing! :(

Comment: @user3170524 have you tried checking what `$db->Quote(JString::strtolower($filter)` contains or doing a query with a hard coded value

Comment: can you explain me how to do it?

Comment: try a `var_dump($db->Quote(JString::strtolower($filter));` to see what its producing and or do `$filterQuery .= " LIKE '%stringtosearch%' ";`